# Where to put Business Rules on ASP.NET Web App, Repository Pattern

Tags: c#, repository, rules

I have been a little confused with trying to determine where to put the business rules for my application.

I am developing an web application using asp.net conventional web forms (not mvc) and on top of that I have a class library where I have the repository pattern for writing to database. I have a "Business Layer" in the repository pattern and also, I am writing stored procedures to affect the tables.

Where should I put for example, Mandatory field validation rules ?

Other example would be, converting foreign currency to USD (i have an exchange rate table, currently I do it in sprocs).

Would you recommend staying away from the sprocs for rules and build everything in my repository business layer ? or In what cases do you recommend building rules and validations within the sprocs ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*This answer is appropriate if you develop a small application that does not use multiple data sources or does not have an extensively unit-tested business layer and if you do not plan to add a service layer (such as for caching). See the opposition in the comments.*

If I may, I can suggest to:

1. Remove repository pattern completely. Do you *really* need to support multiple databases?
2. Keep business logic in a business layer, not database. The benefits are in the locality of the rules. All your domain is expressed as a set of conditions, rules, strategies etc. And it is all located in one place. Should you choose to store them in a database you would create yourself additional headache when maintaining the code.
3. It is easy to unit test code that is in the business layer. I am not sure if it is possible to unit test SP.
4. SP and Repository pattern don't go well together.

Currency rate change every fraction of a second, for this you should use a reliable web service that you can call and get a precise value.

**Summary:**

- Stay away from SP
- Stay away from repository pattern
- Use ORM directly instead of repository pattern abstraction
- Don't mix persistence and business rules
- Separate your business rules in a separate (reusable) assembly

Comment: stay away from repository pattern? why? use ORM within business layer?

Comment: @DarthVader In most cases repository pattern is an overkill. It is *only* appropriate if one needs to support *multiple* data sources. Use ORM for persistence (directly) instead of the abstracted repository pattern. Would you disagree?

Comment: yes, i do disagree. ORM gives u more loose coupling. which you can test in isolation. similarly, if you use repository from business layer, you can mock it and test that easily as well. repository pattern is not only for to be able to change databases easily. it s just another layer, which is fine. I agree it might be overkill for small apps. but once you write a generic one you can import it anywhere.

Comment: one more point, nowadays all these large apps, they use a service layer and inject repositories into it which they inject the services to the Controllers or whatever. With service layer, you can stick memory caches, distributed caches in front of repos. and @oleksii wanna remove it!!

Comment: @DarthVader okay, okay :) I will edit my answer. I agree with your points. The unit tests may also become painful (however in RavenDB they will not). But what I tried to say, that in a small app repository pattern usually becomes an overkill. Simplicity is not necessarily something bad.

Comment: :) well u gain simplicity with repository pattern, separating responsibilities is the first thing to achieve simplicity.

Comment: 1 you since you remove your points about repository pattern.:)

Comment: this answer gives me a little bit more of awareness of what I am doing vs what I am really trying to achieve. thanks a lot for your tips and time

Comment: @Grim, in real-world people do not switch between EF and NHibernate. Unless there's strict business value - it's a waste of time and money. "How do you handle scenarios where an ORM can't be used? " - depends on the project and constraints. For example, command line interfaces, web services, using separate SQL files, embedding SQL with programming code, use a lightweight ORM. There are many choices. I've not said repository pattern tightly couples domain and infra. I said the repo pattern is an overkill for small projects.

Answer (score 1):

- Your repository is NOT supposed to have a business layer. It's sole purpose should be to act as an abstraction of your database. Inside it you manage how you store/retrieve your application data.
- Use SP for database operations that are not subject to frequent change. NEVER put your business logic inside SP. Business logic have tendency to change over time.
- You can create a domain-layer where your business objects reside. Your business object should encapsulate their own validation logic.
- Other than your business/domain objects you may have utility classes (e.g. CurrencyManager or CurrencyHelper) that actually use your business objects to verify business logic against data.
- Finally try to keep your domain free from any sort of presentation/view layer reference. Don't apply business validation rules at view layer or display validation logic at domain layer.

-hope that'll shed some light.